# xamarin image button svg with text (size svg)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, svg, button, xamarin.forms

I want to make a button, image button svg with text.

In xaml:

```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="loginUI.L202">

<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="50">


    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand"/>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="50"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>

    <Button Text=" test" BackgroundColor="Wheat" BorderRadius="20" TextColor="red">
        <Button.Image>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="home.svg" iOS="home.svg"/>
        </Button.Image>
    </Button>

</StackLayout>
```

How to set the size (WidthRequest | HeightRequest) for **home.svg**? TargetType="Image" does not work.

**Or**

There is a way to insert into the button like ?

```
 <Button>  <Path Data="M185.255 512c-76.201 ....." /> </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `Button` if you can use `ImageButton`?

`<ImageButton Source="img.xml" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" />`

But, if you want to use `Button`, then:

`<Button ImageSource="img.xml" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" />`

Why `.xml`?

Because you need to convert your .svg file in a Vector to use as ImageSource of your Button. Use [this link](https://svg2vector.com/) to convert, then, add it on your drawable folder.